# VBA - retrieving cell colours for all cells in a range all at once

Tags: vba, excel

I'm working on an optimization task for our data reconciliation workbook and part of the work the code does is to colour certain cells a specific color based on some conditions. I would like to retrieve all cell colours in a 2D array similarly to how you can retrieve all cell values in a range using:

```
Dim myRangeVals() as Variant
myRangeVals = someRange.value
```

I tried using the following code but `Interior.Color` returns a `Double`:

```
Dim myCellColours() as Variant
myCellColours = someRange.Interior.Color
```

Is there a way to retrieve all cell colours all at once(without looping of course)?

Thanks

Comment: I guess you will need to loop. It works with `.Value` because it can either return a single value or it can already return an array. But `.Interior.Color` returns a `Double` as you correctly wrote and cannot return an array. This indicates that you need a loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is there a way to retrieve all cell colours all at once(without looping of course)?

No, it is not.

Have a look at [Range Object (Excel)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-object-excel).

There you will find  [Range.Value Property (Excel)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/VBA/Excel-VBA/articles/range-value-property-excel) which has a property `RangeValueDataType` which is [xlRangeValueDefault](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/VBA/Excel-VBA/articles/xlrangevaluedatatype-enumeration-excel) by default. And this means:

> ...If the Range object contains more than one cell, returns an array
>   of values...

Thats why the `Range.Value` may be returning an array.

But [Range.Interior Property (Excel)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/VBA/Excel-VBA/articles/range-interior-property-excel):

> Returns an Interior object that represents the interior of the
>   specified object.

This means **one** [Interior Object (Excel)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/VBA/Excel-VBA/articles/interior-object-excel) only for the whole given `Range`.

Comment: Thanks @Axel Richter!